# mat slide toggle is visible over mat-tooltip

Tags: html, css, angular, tooltip, slidetoggle

```css
.error_span .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 22vw;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: black;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 1vh;
    padding-left: 2vh;
    padding: 2vh;
    left: -22vh;
    margin-left: -7em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px #00000029;
    height: 20vh;
}
```

[image]

I have no_of_agents and show names in my div
and i have added tooltip onhover of show names
now the issue is when i hover over show names
tooltip is coming fine but toggle is visible over tooltip
as you see screenshot

Comment: and if you add  a greater value than 1 to z-index (just for debug test, add 999 for example )?

Comment: yes it work z-index-2